# How to access the function inside a future builder from out side Parent widget or another future builder

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a future builder which populate a list view ,inside there is a function total() which calculate ,pick the price of each item  sum it and assign it to the subtotal variable . on the bottom i am showing the total price if i assiggn subtotal variable then it will return 0 for the first time because my function is in future builder ,i mean the function is executed after the value is assign.so i used another future builder for showing the total amount but i cannot access the total function as it is inside the future builder and it cannot be initialzed outside in the class because it has some data that won't be recognized outside.
so the problem is how can i access total function below ,i thought of global key but i don't know how to use it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_ui_kit/models/user.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_ui_kit/screens/checkout.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_ui_kit/util/database_helper.dart';

class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartScreenState createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<CartScreen> {
  var db = new DatabaseHelper();
  int _subTotal = 0;
  List _users = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10.0, 0),

        child: FutureBuilder<List>(
          future: db.getAllUsers(),
          initialData: List(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                      final item = snapshot.data[position];

                   total(){


                        for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
                        if (i == 0){
                          _subTotal =0;
                        }
                        _subTotal = _subTotal +
                            int.parse(
                                User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).price);
                      }
                      return _subTotal;
                   }

                   total();

                    //  print('toatl is $_subTotal');

                      // get your item data here ...
                      return Dismissible(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        child: new Card(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          elevation: 2.0,
                          child: new ListTile(
                            leading: new CircleAvatar(
                              child: Text(
                                  "${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).name.substring(0, 1)}"),
                            ),
                            title: new Text(
                                "User: ${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).price}"),
                            subtitle: new Text(
                                "Id: ${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).id}"),
                            onTap: () => debugPrint(
                                "${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).id}"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        background: slideLeftBackground(),
                        confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
                          if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                            final bool res = await showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "Are you sure you want to delete ${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).name}?"),
                                    actions: <Widget>[
                                      FlatButton(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Cancel",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      FlatButton(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Delete",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          // TODO: Delete the item from DB etc..
                                          setState(() {
                                            // total();
                                            // print(position);

                      print('toatl is $_subTotal');


                                            if (position == 0) {
                                              //print('index 0 dai');
                                              db.deleteUser(User.fromMap(
                                                      snapshot.data[position])
                                                  .id);
                                                  _subTotal = 0;
                     // print('toatl is 0 $_subTotal');


                                              //snapshot.data.removeAt(position);
                                            } else {
                                              snapshot.data
                                                  .removeAt(--position);
                                              db.deleteUser(User.fromMap(
                                                      snapshot.data[position])
                                                  .id);
                                                   total();
                     // print('toatl sewa $_subTotal');


                                            }

                                            //print("removed");
                                            // print('mSubTotal $mSubTotal');
                                          });
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                });
                            return res;
                          }
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
          },
        ),

      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: "Checkout",
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Checkout();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward,
        ),
        heroTag: Object(),
      ),

  bottomSheet: Card(
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: Container(

          child: ListView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(height: 10.0),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,5,5,5),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Total",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),

            FutureBuilder(
            **future: total(),**  the problem is here it cannot be accessed
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                return Text(
                  snapshot.data.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 8,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                );
              }
              return Container();
            }
          ),

                        Text(
                          "Delivery charges included",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 11,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5,5,10,5),
                    width: 150.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      child: Text(
                        "Place Order".toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: (){},
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),



            ],
          ),

          height: 70,
        ),
      ),



    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you can take out your total function and just pass in the data argument once it becomes available in the futurebuilder(like total(data){...}).
Now if you need the data that you got from db.getAllUsers(), you could also create a function like getAllUsers, where you would assign the gotten value to a class variable to be used later. Finally, unless the function total is asynchronous, it does not make sense to have a future builder for it. You can probably get away with calling setState once the total value is available.

Comment: hey i cannot write my total method outside in the class because snapshot.data.length won't be available outside ,
second you suggest set state so i apply my subtotal variable to the text widget ,then please tell me how can i set setState method in text widget ,thanks

Comment: yes you can create a method total(var data) so that when you call it from inside the future builder you just pass the data into the function.

Comment: Then you create another variable for the total sum, and in your total function once you have the sum just assign the value to the sum variable and call setState. Given that text widget is set up to display the sum variable setState will properly update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10.0, 0),
        child: FutureBuilder<List>(
          future: db.getAllUsers(),
          initialData: List(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            total() {
              num subTotal = 0;

              for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
                subTotal += int.parse(User.fromMap(snapshot.data[i]).price);
              }
              setState(() {
                _subTotal=subTotal;
              }); 
            }

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  final item = snapshot.data[position];

                  total();

                  //  print('toatl is $_subTotal');

                  // get your item data here ...
                  return Dismissible(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    child: new Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      elevation: 2.0,
                      child: new ListTile(
                        leading: new CircleAvatar(
                          child: Text(
                              "${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).name.substring(0, 1)}"),
                        ),
                        title: new Text(
                            "User: ${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).price}"),
                        subtitle: new Text(
                            "Id: ${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).id}"),
                        onTap: () => debugPrint(
                            "${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).id}"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    background: slideLeftBackground(),
                    confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
                      if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                        final bool res = await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                content: Text(
                                    "Are you sure you want to delete ${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).name}?"),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Cancel",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Delete",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      // TODO: Delete the item from DB etc..
                                      setState(() {
                                        // total();
                                        // print(position);

                                        print('toatl is $_subTotal');

                                        if (position == 0) {
                                          //print('index 0 dai');
                                          db.deleteUser(User.fromMap(
                                                  snapshot.data[position])
                                              .id);
                                          _subTotal = 0;
                                          // print('toatl is 0 $_subTotal');

                                          //snapshot.data.removeAt(position);
                                        } else {
                                          snapshot.data.removeAt(--position);
                                          db.deleteUser(User.fromMap(
                                                  snapshot.data[position])
                                              .id);
                                          total();
                                          // print('toatl sewa $_subTotal');

                                        }

                                        //print("removed");
                                        // print('mSubTotal $mSubTotal');
                                      });
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            });
                        return res;
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: "Checkout",
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Checkout();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward,
        ),
        heroTag: Object(),
      ),
      bottomSheet: Card(
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: Container(
          child: ListView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 5, 5),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Total",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
// changes

                        Text(
                          _subTotal.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 8,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),

                        Text(
                          "Delivery charges included",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 11,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 10, 5),
                    width: 150.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      child: Text(
                        "Place Order".toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          height: 70,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```